# How to amend a file with sed that would search for one string and then amend additonal text later in the line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a problem with amending a lot of text files that looks like following sample.txt:

```
<p> My very specific text</p>
<p> My blah text</p>
<p> My blah text</p>
<p> My very specific text</p>
<p> My blah text</p>
<p> My blah text</p>
```

so what I need to do is search for the line "very specific", and then insert text before

so it would be sample.txt:

```
<p> My very specific text, thank you</p>
<p> My blah text</p>
<p> My blah text</p>
<p> My very specific text, thank you</p>
<p> My blah text</p>
<p> My blah text</p>
```

I have tried with sed but no matter how I try I fail. I have searched here and on google but it does not help me much not sure if maybe I do not know what do search for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add anything that shows what you have tried, and explain why you think it should have worked.

Comment: In your example, you are not inserting before. Instead you are replacing or appending... depending on the interpretation.

Comment: @Vadniro, apart from adding code you tried, you should also give better sample input/output... else for given sample, you can simply search and replace `very specific text`

Comment: @Sundeep I would have added code but I was not able to figure out logic at all, I know how to use sed to amend/change and replace text but I do not want to change particular text, I want to find lines that contain "very specific" and then only in those lines before </p> to add ", thank you".

Comment: any code at all is better than no code, because you'd get downvotes for no research effort (hover your mouse over downvote button to see it for yourself)... and exactly for that reason I asked to change sample, your current sample doesn't convey your requirements

Comment: @Sundeep thanks I will make note of it and will make sure to include samples in the future that I have tried as I have really tried a lot, but my logic was flawed so I did not feel that comfortable in doing so. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: well if your logic wasn't flawed, you wouldn't have to ask question in first place... think about it.. this forum is about getting help for code one wrote but isn't working... and it would also help others to suggest why your code didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r '/VERY_SPECIFIC/ s/(<\/p>$)/TEXT_TOAPPEND\1/g' file
```

For do rewriting file:

```
sed -r -i.backup '/VERY_SPECIFIC/ s/(<\/p>$)/TEXT_TO_APPEND\1/g' file
```

where

`-r` flag means: use ext regexp

`-i.backup` flag means: rewrite file and make backup with extension `.backup`.

`s/(<\/p>$)/TEXT_TOAPPEND\1/g` is an expression used by sed.

where

`/VERY_SPECIFIC/` is the line to match

`s` means substitute

`<\/p>` is the expression you need, `/` needs to be escaped, or another separator has to be used.

`$` means match pattern ending with endline.

`TEXT_TOAPPEND` the text you need to 'append'.

`g` means substitute all occurences.

Comment: While this code might solve this *specific* problem, this answer might be greatly improved by adding some explaination, what you did. Thank you!

Comment: I'm doing it. Still writing some explanations.

Comment: Hi thanks, but will this not change every </p>? I need to only to amend text that has lines containing "very specific" in this case.

Comment: this changes every p

Comment: you can filter this with sed to match specific lines containing a given string with `'/STRING_CONTAINED_BY_SPECIFIC_LINES/ s/(<\/p>$)/TEXT_TO_APPEND\1/g'` .

Comment: nice @ntj , was not aware of that, this worked. Thank you very much, could you edit your answer so it could be correct one like this:
sed -r '/very specific/ s/(<\/p>$)/TEXT_TO_APPEND\1/g' sample.txt

Comment: suggestions: 1) use another delimiter like `#` or `|` so that you do not need to escape the slash... 2) `-r` is GNU sed specific, use `-E` for better portability... 3) you can avoid capture group by using `&`... 4) no need `g` modifier here... `sed '/very specific/ s|</p>$|TEXT_TOAPPEND&|'`